# Get values from string in querystring format vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to asp.net/vb.net. I have a string that is in querystring format, that is the string is formatted: value1=data1&value2=data2...

I need a way (i'm sure theirs probably a built in function for it) to be able to get the value for any given field such as Dim data1 = string.querystring("value1"). I googlged it and found the function querystring but it only seems to work on getting straight from a URL, but I have that data stored in a string variable and want to get the data from this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`, you can call it in any context as it just expects string parameter. Just add a reference to `System.Web`, you can do it even it desktop apps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong i'm still getting errors and i'm completely stuck I implemented it as below how should I have done it? :

Comment: `code`  Public Shared Sub ProcessString(ByVal Istring As String)
        Dim var As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Istring)
        Dim Params As String = IPN.QueryString("var1")
    End Sub 'code'

Comment: Ask it as another question. Include your code and information on the error.